# cqlsh will not run on OS X

Tags: macos, cassandra, cqlsh

I installed Cassandra on Big Sur 11.4 using homebrew, and when I tried to run cqlsh, I received this error.

```
isaackim@Isaacs-MacBook-Pro bin % cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.10/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2458, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.10/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2232, in read_options
    configs.read(CONFIG_FILE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

I previously had Anaconda3 installed, and received the same error (the only difference was the path to cqlsh.py). I thought it might be an issue with Anaconda so I uninstalled Anaconda entirely, then I reinstalled Cassandra using homebrew.

I would appreciate any and all suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` or `~/.cqlshrc`  file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Ott's suggestion, I managed to replicate the issue you posted by creating a bad `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` configuration file which only contains the following line:

```
username = alice
```

As this error suggests:

```
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

the configuration parser detected that there are no section headers in the file. Section headers are line entries enclosed in square brackets (`[header_name]`). For example:

```
[authentication]
username = alice
password = Som3Comp7exPa$$word
```

Review your `cqlshrc` and make the necessary corrections. If necessary, use the example `cqlshrc.sample` file in `conf/`. Cheers!